# collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath stopped working after migrated to Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, collectionview, swift5

I just upgraded my Xcode to version 10.2, after I installed the latest Mojave macOS.

Xcode asked me to migrate my Swift from 3.0 to later versions, so I chose to update to Swift 5.0.

After a few minor changes regarding grammar change, the app is up and running. However, I found that 
collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath stopped working in the simulator or device, which means when you tap on an item in the collectionView, the corresponding didSelectItemAtIndexPath method is not longer being called.

I examined my code changes many times, I am pretty sure the grammar changes are unrelated to the collectionViews being affected. I can make some TagGesture tricks to work around, but I wonder what's the problem here.

I am pretty sure the collection view allows user interaction, and allows selection too.

What's going on here?

update:

My old code has no changes at all after the migration, it looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
...
}
```

I updated to the following per answerers' suggestion. However, still not working.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
...
}
```

(I didn't even touch the xib file too, the delegates are all correct.)

Comment: Please show the relevant code - ie. your `didSelectItem(at:)` function

Comment: there was no change at this code at all, all the changes are unrelated to the collection view at all

Comment: There may be code changes required, that is why I am asking to see your code.

Comment: @paulw11 please take a look at the code. the current things is this method isn't being called at all when click on an item.

Comment: What is the value of your collection view's `allowsSelection` property? either set through code or through the xib file.

Comment: I set it to true from code, after I saw a post mentions it. before I didn't set it at all.

Comment: Have you set a break point in `didSelectItemAt` to confirm that it isn't actually being called?

Comment: yeah, that's how I found out it is not called.

Comment: The collection view still respond to scroll gesture, when you scroll, it still moves, just doesn't respond to single tap

Comment: This is unlikely to be a Swift version issue since you are experiencing a problem with UIKit, not Swift. Can you roll back to the Swift 3 code and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I can't, because my xCode and macOS has been changed to the latest, it no longer support swift 3.0 any more. My last xCode update was in last autumn, which is about 6 months ago. Lately apple asked all apps to do an update, that's why I am trying to migrate.

Comment: You can download older versions of Xcode from Apples developer site

Comment: I reverted all my changes, and then convert from swift 3 to swift 4, which it supported, and narrowed down the changes to 3 or 4 minor changes, I can see clearly that nothing in my code was affecting the collection view at all. just too far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate method was probably renamed.  Check that you're implementing:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Also double-check that you're still setting the controller as a delegate for the UICollectionView.

Comment: thanks! please check my edits, looks to me one of the parameter did renamed, but after changed to the new name, still doesn't work...

Comment: Are you implementing shouldSelectItemAt anywhere?  Make sure that returns true.  Also, I saw above that you fixed the name of the delegate method, but did you verify the delegate is set correctly?

Comment: didn't have shouldSelectItemAt method at all. Also, the delegate are correct, the xib file has no changes, all the delegate are still pointing to the same places.

Comment: according to apple:
If you do not implement this method, the default return value is true

Comment: Yeah, that should return true.  Also might want to check that your delegate extends UICollectionViewDelegate.  Since. you're setting that from the XIB file, it might not warn you if it doesn't conform to that protocol.

Comment: the delegate is xib file's owner, which is this file:class EditorViewController: UIViewController, SlideExitCallBackHandler {

Comment: That should be `EditorViewController: UIViewController, SlideExitCallBackHandler, UICollectionViewDelegate {`

Comment: wow it finally works. this must be a new requirement in the newer versions of swift I guess? cause the file doesn't have this inheritance but has always been working fine.

Comment: Surprised that apple doesn't even mention these in documents.

Comment: UICollectionView is probably written in Obj-C, so it would just check that the delegate implements that method, but they probably updated it to double-check that the delegate implements the protocol first.

Comment: Posting here to in case people are watching the answer: get us some upvotes here to fix this https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2919

Comment: @FernandoMazzon Just saw your bug been fixed. Thanks for recording this!

Answer (score 4):

Check out this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393950/1943064

Essentially there's a bug on swift 5 regarding the implementation of optional methods of protocols that are implemented by a superclass. If the optional method is missing in the superclass, it's identified as missing in the subclass as well.

I ended up there after passing through this thread. This was the real culprit for me. Also keep in mind that making any changes on the file while building on dev might randomly fix the issue (Like adding the shouldSelectItemAt that some people suggested. I did that, and it fixed it, and then I removed it and it kept working. My circleCI build however was still broken 100% of the time).

Comment: I followed the comments under mikepj's answer, and it solved my issue.

Comment: @RainCast But was any of your superclasses already implementing the protocol? If not, it's proper that it didn't work.

Comment: But it works in previous versions, these are not new code. Seems the new swift requires it more strictly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put a button or an interactive view in a collection view cell? Your touch is handled by it, then didSelect is not called.

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Oddly, this issue only happened in my case with older iOS versions (older devices), but this took care of it.

Comment: this question is already resolved, please see the answer being marked. thanks!